# Angular Controller As Syntax-no method '$watchCollection'

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to do Controller As Syntax in Angular. At this point, I have it in my routerProvider...not sure if it would matter for the issue I am having, but here it is anyways:

```
 angular.module('ucp.kick', [
  'ngRoute'
])
.config ($routeProvider, APP_BASE_URL) ->
  $routeProvider
  .when APP_BASE_URL + 'kicks',
    name: 'Kicks'
    templateUrl: 'kick/partials/kick.html'
    controller: 'kick as KickController'
```

Here is a condensed version of my controller I have:

```
  this.$watchCollection('filtered.devices', function(devices) {
    return this.filteredDevices = devices;
  });
```

But I get:

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method '$watchCollection'
```

I realize when using the controller as syntax, you do not want inject the scope. So, how do I access `$watchCollection` function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will still need to inject `$scope` in order to use `$watch` and `$watchCollection`.  Now, you would think you could do:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('filtered.devices', function (newVal, oldVal) {});
```

or

```
$scope.$watchCollection('this.filtered.devices', function (newVal, oldVal) {});
```

But that won't work.  So you need to either do:

```
var that = this;
$scope.$watchCollection(function () {
    return that.filtered.devices;
}, function (newVal, oldVal) {

});
```

or:

```
$scope.$watchCollection(angular.bind(this, function () {
    return this.filtered.devices;
}), function (newVal, oldVal) {

});
```

or:

```
$scope.$watchCollection("KickController.filtered.devices", function(newVal, oldVal) { });
```

Comment: Fascinating! Never new about `that`

Answer (score 1):

For watches, you still need to use `$scope`.

After injecting `$scope` into your controller, as you would have before the `controllerAs` syntax came about, you could do: `$scope.$watchCollection(..)`

To further iterate on what I mean: if the value you are trying to watch is bound to a value using the `controllerAs` syntax -- such as `kickController.someValue` then you would watch that value `$scope.$watchCollection('kickController.someValue',...)`

Sidenote: showing all of your code would help because it looks like you could have your controller definition backwards. Did you mean to do:
`...
controller: KickController as kick`

and then:

`var kick = this;`

?

Answer (score 1):

`controller as` does not replace the controller with `$scope`.  Controllers don't have a `$watchCollection` property.  You still have to inject `$scope` and use `$scope.$watchCollection` *and* you have to use the controller identifier as the name of the collection to watch

```
$scope.$watchCollection("KickController.filtered.devices"
```

That being said, using `$watch` and `$watchCollection` can usually be avoided and you can just work with the data bindings. Angular will use `$watchCollection` internally on the collection.  Specifically I'm not sure that you need this other property `filteredDevices` when you can just use a filter explicitly on the existing collection.