# AngularJS - Watch array and update object

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to figure out how to watch an array and update an object, like this.

```
var vm = this; //controller
vm.order = {
    totalValue: 25,
    products: [{id:0, val: 10, qtd: 1}, {id:1, val: 15, qtd: 1}]
};
```

If I push a new product into this order object, how do I update the totalValue just watching the collection ? (totalValue = All Val * All Qtd)

It is necessary because the "qtd" field is bind to an input field, so I can change the value of all "products" at any time.

**UPDATE**

```
$scope.$watchCollection(
            function() { return self.order.products; }, 
            function(products) {
                self.order.totalValue = products.reduce(function (p, n) {
                    console.log(n.qtd);
                    console.log(n.val);
                    return p + n.qtd * n.val;
                }, 0);
            });
```

The code worked, but only when I push a new "product" into order.
I have to watch every order.products.product.qtd and change the order.totalValue every time the user change the qtd of a product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$scope.$watch('order.products', function (products) {
    scope.order.totalValue = products.reduce(function (p, n) {
        return p + n.qtd * n.val;
    }, 0);
}, true);
```

This will deep watch array to detect qtd and val changes inside array items.

Comment: What if I have instead of "$scope.orders" I has "var vm = this; vm.orders" ?

I've updated the question

Comment: Then you'll have to adjust your function accordingly like [described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30874412/angular-controller-as-syntax-no-method-watchcollection).

Comment: Thanks very much for the help @karaxuna